# Inserting into table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this table on an Oracle server with this structure:

```
Create table temp
(
    input number(10),
    str varchar(24),

    constraint L_PK PRIMARY KEY(input, str)
)
```

I made one alteration on it:

```
alter table temp add userID number(10);
```

Now I am trying to do an insert:

```
insert into temp values (9, 7, 'sure.');
```

But I am getting a error saying:

> ORA-01722: Invalid Number

Any ideas? I'm pretty sure its coming from the 'sure' but I can't say for sure.

Comment: It should be `(number, varchar, number)`, so `(9, 'sure', 7)`.

Comment: I think you might have an invalid number.

Answer (score 4):

Specify the column-names when you are inserting so the appropriate data is inserted into the columns.

```
insert into temp (input, userid, str)
values (9, 7, 'sure.');
```

Comment: +1 as my experience tells me always to list the column names to avoid the problem described here and to be future proof when new columns are added.

Answer (score 4):

So you created a table with two columns:

```
Create table temp(
input      number(10),
str      varchar(24),
constraint L_PK PRIMARY KEY(input,str),
```

Made one alteration to it:

```
alter table temp add userID number(10);
```

Which leaves you with a table with columns *input*, *str*, and *userID* in that order. You then try to insert

```
insert into temp values (9, 7, 'sure.');
```

which tries to insert *9* into *input* (fine), *7* into *str* (not fine), and *sure* into *userID* (again, not fine).

You need to either use the values in the proper order to match the column order:

```
insert into temp values (9, 'sure', 7);
```

or (much better and safer) specify the columns first, and then assign the values to match:

```
insert into temp (input, userID, str) values (7, 9, 'sure');
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case:

> insert into temp values (9, 7, 'sure.');

It means:

```
INSERT INTO temp (input, str, userId)
VALUES (9, 7, 'sure.');
```

As 'sure.' does not a number type, Oracle server certainly gets error.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't change the insert order,you should change the alteration SQL:

> alter table temp add userID number(10) **after str**;

Yes,'after str' is appended.
Or you could change the insert order like this:insert into temp values (9, 'sure', 7);

Whatever you must remember that column should match with the value,especially in datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You added userID at the end of the table. Try

```
insert into temp values (9, 'sure.', 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding column,it is added at the end of the table

insert into temp values (9,  'sure.',7);

### output:

input   str  userID
  9    sure.    7